# Error with .toLowerCase and null property

Tags: javascript, while-loop

What I'm trying to do is make a user able to enter multiple options from a prompt, and I can't make it so that it doesn't matter if "rcz" is entered with or without capital letters, I always get the same error.
I need my counter to appear in the console, but instead I got this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')

Code I'm using:

```js
alert(`Choose one or more cars. If you want to stop press ESC`);
let userPrompt = prompt(`Available cars: 208, 308, RCZ`);
let promptToLC = userPrompt.toLowerCase();
let counter = 0;
while(userPrompt != null) {
    switch(promptToLC) {
        default:
            alert(`We don't have that car. Try again.`);
            break;
        case "208":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
        case "308":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
        case "rcz":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
    }
    userPrompt = prompt(`Available cars: 208, 308, RCZ`);
    promptToLC = userPrompt.toLowerCase();
}
console.log(counter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prompt(`Available cars: 208, 308, RCZ`);
```

returns a string or `null`. `userPrompt.toLowerCase();` causes an error if `userPrompt` is `null`. You can fix it with [conditional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
alert(`Choose one or more cars. If you want to stop press ESC`);
let userPrompt = prompt(`Available cars: 208, 308, RCZ`);
let promptToLC = userPrompt?.toLowerCase();
let counter = 0;
while(userPrompt != null) {
    switch(promptToLC) {
        default:
            alert(`We don't have that car. Try again.`);
            break;
        case "208":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
        case "308":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
        case "rcz":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
    }
    userPrompt = prompt(`Available cars: 208, 308, RCZ`);
    promptToLC = userPrompt?.toLowerCase();
}
console.log(counter);
```

or a modified logic without `promptToLC`:

```js
alert(`Choose one or more cars. If you want to stop press ESC`);
let userPrompt = prompt(`Available cars: 208, 308, RCZ`);
let counter = 0;
while(userPrompt != null) {
    // const promptToLC = userPrompt.toLowerCase();
    switch(userPrompt.toLowerCase()) {
        default:
            alert(`We don't have that car. Try again.`);
            break;
        case "208":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
        case "308":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
        case "rcz":
            counter = counter + 1;
            break;
    }
    userPrompt = prompt(`Available cars: 208, 308, RCZ`);
}
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: The change of logic helped me a lot, I'm starting in JavaScript and I'm having a hard time finding different solutions for the same problem, I hadn't thought it that way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because there is a chance that 'userPrompt' is null in the case that the user cancels the prompt with no input.

You can assert that the prompt is not null by changing your statement to:

```
let promptToLC = (userPrompt ? userPrompt:"").toLowerCase();
```

This conditional statement will ensure that in the case "userPrompt" is null (falsey value by default), the null value will not be used and instead the empty string will be.